# Hibernate throws javax.persistence.PersistenceException only when number of records is 1 (possible bug?)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2, hibernate-search

My entity is as follows :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "segment_meta")
@Indexed
public class SegmentMeta implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name ="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @Field(name = "userId", analyze = Analyze.NO)
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "segment_id", unique = true)
    @Field(name = "segmentId", analyze = Analyze.NO)
    private String segmentId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @Field(name = "segment_name", analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "englishAnalyzer"))
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "segment_condition")
    private String condition;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    //(mappedBy = "featureRefMeta",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderColumn
    @JoinTable(name = "join_tbl_segment_to_feature_ref_meta",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "segment_id", referencedColumnName = "segment_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "feature_ref_meta_id", referencedColumnName = "feature_ref_meta_id")})
    private List<FeatureRefMeta> featureRefList;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderColumn
    @JoinTable(name = "join_tbl_segment_to_easy_id_set_ref_meta",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "segment_id", referencedColumnName = "segment_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "easy_id_set_ref_meta_id", referencedColumnName = "easy_id_set_ref_meta_id")})
    private List<EasyIdSetRefMeta> easyIdSetRefList;

  }
```

Repository:

```
public interface SegmentMetaRepository extends JpaRepository<SegmentMeta, Long> {

    SegmentMeta findBySegmentId(String segmentId);
}
```

My Unit test,

```
@Test
    public void testSegmentSearch() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            SegmentMeta sm = new SegmentMeta();
            sm.setName("Segment name-" + i);
            sm.setCondition("1 OR 2");
            sm.setUserId("user1");
            sm.setSegmentId("segment_" + i);
            segmentMetaRepository.save(sm);
        }

        SegmentMetaSearchResult res = featureMetaSearchRepository.searchSegments(0, 50, "name-", null);
        assertThat(res.getTotalCount()).isEqualTo(1);
        assertThat(res.getResults().size()).isEqualTo(1);
    }
```

When i=1, Hibernate throws following error,but for any number >1 it works fine.Error is throwing when calling "featureMetaSearchRepository.searchSegments()"

> 2017-12-28 16:43:08,414 - [main] - [INFO ] -
>   [org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(line:129)]
>   - HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error
>   accessing field [private java.lang.String
>   com.mycompany.cdna.dataaccess.model.meta.segment.SegmentMeta.segmentId]
>   by reflection for persistent property
>   [com.mycompany.cdna.dataaccess.model.meta.segment.SegmentMeta#segmentId]
>   : 1 org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error
>   accessing field [private java.lang.String
>   com.mycompany.cdna.dataaccess.model.meta.segment.SegmentMeta.segmentId]
>   by reflection for persistent property
>   [com.mycompany.cdna.dataaccess.model.meta.segment.SegmentMeta#segmentId]
>   : 1   at
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:74)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:59)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getPropertyValue(ComponentType.java:412)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getHashCode(ComponentType.java:239)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionKey.generateHashCode(CollectionKey.java:64)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionKey.(CollectionKey.java:58)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionKey.(CollectionKey.java:43)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.getLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:95)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.finishUpRow(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:105)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:121)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails$EntityLoaderRowReader.readRow(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:241)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:122)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4083)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1239)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1900(SessionImpl.java:203)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2804)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2778)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.ObjectLoaderHelper.executeLoad(ObjectLoaderHelper.java:61)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.ObjectLoaderHelper.load(ObjectLoaderHelper.java:37)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.QueryLoader.executeLoad(QueryLoader.java:64)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.AbstractLoader.load(AbstractLoader.java:64)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.doHibernateSearchList(FullTextQueryImpl.java:239)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.list(FullTextQueryImpl.java:222)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.getResultList(FullTextQueryImpl.java:121)
>     at
>   com.mycompany.cdna.dataaccess.repository.FeatureSegmentMetaSearchRepository.findEntities(FeatureSegmentMetaSearchRepository.java:64)
>     at
>   com.mycompany.cdna.dataaccess.repository.FeatureSegmentMetaSearchRepository.searchSegments(FeatureSegmentMetaSearchRepository.java:77)
>     at
>   com.mycompany.cdna.dataaccess.repository.FeatureSegmentMetaSearchRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$91b0147b.invoke()

Has anyone encountered this issue ? Could this be a Hibernate bug ?

*Hibernate 5.0.1 , Spring Boot 2.0.0M*

**Update** Search Repository :

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class FeatureSegmentMetaSearchRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private <T> List<T> findEntities(Class<T> clz, AbstractSearchResult out, String fieldName, Integer offset, Integer pageSize, String text, String userId) {
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
                org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.
                        getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
        QueryBuilder queryBuilder =
                fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
                        .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(clz).get();
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query queryKeyword;
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            queryKeyword = queryBuilder.all().createQuery();
        } else {
            queryKeyword = queryBuilder
                    .keyword()
                    .onFields(fieldName)
                    .matching(text)
                    .createQuery();
        }
        BooleanQuery.Builder aggrBuilder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
        aggrBuilder = aggrBuilder.add(new BooleanClause(queryKeyword, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));

        if (userId != null) {
            TermQuery queryFilter = new TermQuery(new Term("userId", userId));
            aggrBuilder = aggrBuilder.add(new BooleanClause(queryFilter, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
        }

        org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery jpaQuery =
                fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(aggrBuilder.build(), clz);
        if (offset != null) jpaQuery.setFirstResult(offset);
        if (pageSize != null) jpaQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize);
        out.setTotalCount(jpaQuery.getResultSize());
        List r = jpaQuery.getResultList();
        return (List<T>) r;
    }

    public PresentationLayerMetaSearchResult searchPresentationLayers(Integer offset, Integer pageSize, String text, String userId) {
        PresentationLayerMetaSearchResult ret = new PresentationLayerMetaSearchResult();
        List<PresentationLayerMeta> lst = findEntities(PresentationLayerMeta.class, ret, "pres_layer_name", offset, pageSize, text, userId);
        ret.setResults(lst);
        return ret;
    }

    public SegmentMetaSearchResult searchSegments(Integer offset, Integer pageSize, String text, String userId) {
        SegmentMetaSearchResult ret = new SegmentMetaSearchResult();
        List<SegmentMeta> lst = findEntities(SegmentMeta.class, ret, "segment_name", offset, pageSize, text, userId);
        ret.setResults(lst);
        return ret;
    }


    public FeatureMetaSearchResult searchFeatures(Integer offset, Integer pageSize, String text, String categoryId, String featureSetId, Collection<String> tags) {
        FeatureMetaSearchResult ret = new FeatureMetaSearchResult();
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
                org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.
                        getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
        //Filtering by keyword
        QueryBuilder queryBuilder =
                fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
                        .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(FeatureMeta.class).get();
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query queryKeyword;
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            queryKeyword = queryBuilder.all().createQuery();
        } else {
            queryKeyword = queryBuilder
                    .keyword()
                    .onFields("name_en", "name_ja", "desc_en", "desc_ja", "business_desc_en", "business_desc_ja",
                            "logical_desc_en", "logical_desc_ja")
                    .matching(text)
                    .createQuery();
        }
        BooleanQuery.Builder aggrBuilder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
        aggrBuilder = aggrBuilder.add(new BooleanClause(queryKeyword, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));

        if (categoryId != null) {
            TermQuery queryFilter = new TermQuery(new Term("categoryId", categoryId));
            aggrBuilder = aggrBuilder.add(new BooleanClause(queryFilter, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
        }
        if (featureSetId != null) {
            String setFilter = new EnumBridge().objectToString(featureSetId);
            TermQuery queryFilter = new TermQuery(new Term("featureSetId", setFilter));
            aggrBuilder = aggrBuilder.add(new BooleanClause(queryFilter, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
        }

        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(tags)) {
            for (String tag : tags) {
                TermQuery queryFilter = new TermQuery(new Term("tags", tag));
                aggrBuilder = aggrBuilder.add(new BooleanClause(queryFilter, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
            }
        }

        org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery jpaQuery =
                fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(aggrBuilder.build(), FeatureMeta.class);

        if (offset != null) jpaQuery.setFirstResult(offset);
        if (pageSize != null) jpaQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize);

        ret.setTotalCount(jpaQuery.getResultSize());
        ret.setResults(jpaQuery.getResultList());
        return ret;
    }
}
```

**Update 2:**
I create multiple records of SegmentMeta (eg, seg1,seg2,seg3..etc). And when I search for search result having 1 record (eg : seg2) , this error is thrown.

Comment: What if you add public getter/setter for the field `segmentId`?

Comment: have you tried by setting ---  for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) ?

Comment: @StanislavL ist already there..  public String getSegmentId() { return segmentId;}
public void setSegmentId(String segmentId) {this.segmentId = segmentId;}

Comment: @maddy23285 int=1;i<2 also throws the same error.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint at GetterFieldImpl.java:74 and debug. That could give your more details on what the problem is accessing the field...

Comment: Could you try to reproduce your issue with our test case template: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/search/hibernate-search-lucene - keeping it as simple as possible? With all the Spring Boot magic, it's hard to say if the issue is coming from Hibernate (ORM or Search). Thanks.